# How can I achieve this cartoon-like effect?

Tags: photoshop

Would really like to know how to edit a photo to get this effect. Its kind of like a cartoon effect but not the kind i'm used to seeing.

http://d.yimg.com/hd/answers/i/dcd80a1aca7241ca81a2936c1efcb2f5_A.jpeg?a=answers&mr=0&x=1387176036&s=48816aa9ed3b7e6049cd1e1ea0d257fc

Comment: If you want answers, your best bet is to put something descriptive in the question title - will also help other people find the answer later.  "cartoon-like" if nothing else.

Comment: Or might be better to ask at: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm getting an "Unauthorized" response from d.yimg.com :-(

Comment: I have no problem seeing the image at the link.

Comment: Until I try to refresh it. Now I can't.

Comment: Hmm... works if I click directly (rather than opening in a new tab).

Comment: Doesn't for me (any more). I'm still *Unauthorized*.

Comment: please update the photo url, it doesn't work

Comment: Voting to close as unclear what you are asking because the link is no longer valid and the description does not provide sufficient detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some Photoshop filter effects (emboss, plastic wrap) that might get you close.  The closest thing I know of are some of the Topaz filters.

I think the closest are the cartoon filters from the Topaz Clean product (Cartoon, Crisp Style and Curly Smooth).  Topaz Adjust will also have similar effects.

These filters smooth out small detail (which the Topaz Clean product does generally) but enhances the contrast of large edges.  You can adjust the smoothing effect and the edge effect to your liking.  Topaz works with Photoshop (CS and Elements), Lightroom, Aperture, and some [other image editors](http://www.topazlabs.com/support/kb/index.php?View=entry&EntryID=17).

[image]

Comment: closest answer I've gotten so far. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Frank - Well, that's partly because none of us can access the image you linked to...